# Copiar de arquivo txt para o outro

Tags: c, c++

```
int main(void) {
    void copiaConteudo(FILE *arquivo, FILE *arquivo1);
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("tmp/exercicio.txt","r");
    if (arquivo == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Não foi possível abrir o arquivo");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *arquivo1 = fopen("home/novo.txt","w");    
    copiaConteudo(arquivo,arquivo1);        
    fclose(arquivo);
    fclose(arquivo1);
    return 0;
}

void copiaConteudo(FILE *arquivo, FILE *arquivo1)
{
    string teste;
    teste = "Teste";
    char ler[100];
    while(fgets(ler,100,arquivo) != NULL)

    if (ler.find("Teste"))
    {
        fputs("0/",arquivo);    
    }
    else
    {
        fputs(ler, arquivo1);
    }
}
```

Eu tenho esse código, que minha intenção é copiar do arquivo exercicio.txt para o arquivo novo.txt, eu consigo copiar tudo, mas agora eu queria incluir um parâmetro para ele não copiar as linhas que contém "teste".
Meu `if` ali no final é minha tentativa que não deu certo, como eu posso fazer isto?

Comment: Parece que vc quer fazer uma coisa simples, mas não da para entender bem a explicação, consegui detalhar ?

Comment: O ideal é ler o arquivo e fazer a busca na memória. Mas pode ser que o objetivo seja outro.

Comment: Eu quero copiar tudo que tem no arquivo exercicio.txt para o arquivo novo.txt, mas quero criar um parametro, para tudo que começar com Teste, não entrar no fputs(ler,arquivo1); Que é a função que está copiando o conteúdo do arquivo exercicio.txt

Comment: Vc tem que decidir qual linguagem que quer explanar o problema. C é diferente de C++

Answer (score 4):

Segue uma solução (testada) em linguagem `C` capaz de realizar uma cópia binária bufferizada de dois arquivos:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    FILE * src = NULL;
    FILE * dst = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    size_t m = 0;
    unsigned char buf[ 1024 * 8 ];


    /* Verifica sintaxe */
    if( argc != 3 )
    {
        printf("Erro de sintaxe: %s ARQUIVO_ORIGEM ARQUIVO_DESTINO\n", argv[0] );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Abre arquivo de origem para leitura  */
    src = fopen( argv[1], "rb" );

    if(!src)
    {
        printf("Erro abrindo arquivo de origem para leitura: %s [%s]\n", argv[1], strerror(errno) );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    /* Abre arquivo de destino para gravacao */
    dst = fopen( argv[2], "wb" );

    if(!dst)
    {
        fclose(src);
        printf("Erro abrindo arquivo de destino para escrita: %s [%s]\n", argv[2], strerror(errno) );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Efetua a copia dos arquivos */
    do {
        m = 0;

        n = fread( buf, 1, sizeof(buf), src );

        if( n > 0 )
            m = fwrite( buf, 1, n, dst );

    } while( (n > 0) && (n == m) );

    /* Verifica se houve erro durante a copia */
    if( m )
    {
        printf("Erro copiando arquivo: %s\n", strerror(errno) );

        fclose(dst);
        fclose(src);

        remove(argv[2]); /* Remove arquivo parcialmente copiado */

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Finaliza com sucesso */

    fclose(dst);
    fclose(src);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, mas copiar eu já consigo, a minha questão é ter uma condição para não copiar por exemplo as palavras que contenham "TESTE", não estou conseguindo achar uma forma de incluir isso, estou o dia inteiro lendo no site da C++ sobre string::find, mas não consigo aplicar na utilização em arquivo

Answer (score 4):

Bom, como vc etiquetou a pergunta com `C++` e realmente parece que está usando o `C++` para algumas funções de alto nível (`string::find()` por exemplo), vou dar uma resposta usando apenas o `C++`.

Comentando um pouco sobre a função [string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), se ela encontra o valor pedido, ela retorna a posição em que ele começa na `string`, caso contrário, retorna o valor `std::string::npos`

Segue abaixo um programa funcional o qual elimina qualquer linha que tenha palavra 'teste'

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto input = std::ifstream("exercicio.txt");
    auto output = std::ofstream("novo.txt");

    std::string msg;
    while (std::getline(input, msg))
    {
        if ( msg.find("teste") != std::string::npos )
            continue;
        output << msg << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se for válido usar linha de comando (como as que existem em linux, mac,
mesmo em windows) o conceito de **filtro** pode ser interessante. Um filtro
aceita uma entrada textual e devolve uma saida tambem textual -- o que permite encadeamentos, e pode ser usado como ferramenta aplicável a 
a variados ficheiros de entrada.

Via linha de comando podemos usar filtros criados por nós ou existentes no
sistema operativo em questão.

Hipótese 1: filtro predefinido **grep** (linux, mac ou windows com utilitarios gnu instalados)

```
 grep -v 'teste' < exercicio.txt > novo.txt
```

**grep -v** -- deixa passar apenas as linhas que não contêm a expressão regular correspontende ao primeiro parametro

Hipótese 2: filtro criado pelo utilizador (baseado na solução @Amadeus (+1))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   string msg;
   if (argc == 2 ){
      while (getline(cin,msg)) {
         if ( msg.find(argv[1]) == string::npos )
            cout << msg << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Este filtro está a receber o padrão de rejeição por argumento. Uso:

```
g++ -o filtro filtro.cpp
filtro teste < exercicio.txt > novo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu não consegui entender muito bem do std::find, mas irei usar seus exemplos para treinar, muito obrigado pelas respostas!

Acabei resolvendo desta maneira:

```
int main(void) {
  void copiaConteudo(FILE *arquivo, FILE *arquivo1);
  FILE *arquivo = fopen("tmp/exercicio.txt","r");
if (arquivo == NULL)
{
    printf ("Não foi possível abrir o arquivo");
    return 1;
}

FILE *arquivo1 = fopen("home/novo.txt","w");

copiaConteudo(arquivo,arquivo1);

fclose(arquivo);
fclose(arquivo1);
return 0;
}

void copiaConteudo(FILE *arquivo, FILE *arquivo1)
{

  char ler[100];
  char lu[20];
  while(fgets(ler,100,arquivo) != NULL)
{
        if (strcmp(ler,"Teste") < 0)
        {
            fputs(ler, arquivo1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Fiz mais um edit, é que ainda estou engatinhando no Stackoverflow :D